# My compileSdkVersion is set to 30 but Android Studio showing Error that it's set to 29

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build a flutter app but `gradle build` error is occurring whenever I am trying to sync the gradle after hitting `Open for editing in Android studio`. Showing this weird error that shouldn't be there. I have my app running on API Level 30 emulator and it's running perfectly fine only this is the issue that is not just fixing. Please help this is just not working and I'm stuck here for weeks. Below is the app/build.gradle file.

```
Error: The compileSdkVersion (29) should not be lower than the targetSdkVersion (30) 
[GradleCompatible]
  compileSdkVersion 29



    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.reonemoretimewaapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your app/build.gradle?

Comment: compileSdkVersion can't be lower than targetSdkVersion. Use the same number for both of them

Comment: Please show your full android/app/build.gradle file

Comment: It looks alright. Try `flutter clean` and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to build.gradle file of Project level.

```
 subprojects { subproject ->
        afterEvaluate{
            if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after adding above block of code it will look like this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 32
        buildToolsVersion = "32.0.0"
    }
 subprojects { subproject ->
        afterEvaluate{
            if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps and save your time.

Credit (Reference): [In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644279/in-order-to-compile-java-9-source-please-set-compilesdkversion-to-30-or-above/76662951#76662951) (Username: ut9081)