# In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

Tags: android

I am trying to build a project in Android Studio and getting this error

> In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

In my `android/build.gradle` file I have set

```
 compileSdkVersion = 33
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the complete `build.gradle` file if it is fine? It will be better to analyze that way.

Answer (score 43):

You can fix ths by adding this code to the `buildscript` section in your build.gradle file:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So afterwards it should look something like:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    }
    subprojects { subproject ->
        afterEvaluate{
            if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will apply compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to any android modules you have.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736483

Comment: THANK YOU! I have no idea why RN don't document this!

Comment: The issue with this is the build.gradle gets generated everytime yarn is run inside the react-native-msal library. So if you are running a project with this library in any devops cloud you are screwed because you can't make these manual changes in the `node_modules`

Comment: Thank you! This got me past a major headache, but now I'm erroring out on:  Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. So will keep hunting for a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too today. In my case one of the dependencies (`react-native-azure-auth`) in my react native project was using an older `compileSdkVersion` (29). Fixed it by patching the dependency to use the `compileSdkVersion` from `android/build.gradle` (https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth/issues/185) and also opened a PR for it (https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth/pull/186).