# Problem wit react-native-selectable-text package

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-native-cli

I am trying to use react-native-selectable-text in my react native project. but when I build the project on android emulator it fails and this message appears

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

`* What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-selectable-text:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'. > Could not create task ':react-native-selectable-text:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above`

Can any body tell me how can I solve this problem please?

I did the steps of adding package according to the instructions in [documantation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alentoma/react-native-selectable-text#manual-installation) but as I using kotlin instead of java When adding  `RNSelectableTextPackage()` to the list returned by `getPackages` function in `MainActivity.kt` I couldn't find the `getPackages` function so I added this lines to the 'MainActivity' class

`override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> = PackageList(this).packages.apply { new RNSelectableTextPackage() }`

I tried this by both "add" and "new", but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76662951/14631925)

by adding the code below to buildscripts section in build.gradle file:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
afterEvaluate{
    if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
            buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- The error message you're seeing is because the react-native-selectable-text package requires a compileSdkVersion of 30 or above. This is because the package uses Java 9+ features, which are not supported by default in older versions of Android.
- Open your android/app/build.gradle file & Update the compileSdkVersion to 30 or above.

  ```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 30 // or a higher version
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourprojectname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Regarding the getPackages function, it seems like you're using a Kotlin-based React Native project. In this case, you should add the RNSelectableTextPackage to the list of packages returned by the packages function in your MainActivity.kt

  ```
  override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> {
    return PackageList(this).packages.apply {
        add(RNSelectableTextPackage())
    }
  }
  ```

Note : If you're using a newer version of React Native that uses autolinking, you may not need to manually add the package to the list of packages.